# Запятая перед союзом "если"

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в предложении "Вид проснувшейся могучей реки являл собой если не странное, то по истине величественное зрелище" перед союзом "если" запятая не ставится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, поистине - наречие, слитно.

Во-вторых,предложение не сложное с подчинительным союзом если,а простое с двойным союзом    "если  не...то", соединяющим однородные члены и выполняющим  сочинительную функцию, как и союзы "как...так и" , "не только...но и "

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста,  как будет выглядеть схема.

Comment: Вид проснувшейся могучей реки являл собой если не странное, то поистине величественное зрелище.[-  = ]Вид - подлежащее, являл собой зрелище - сказуемое,зрелище какое?-если не странное, то величественное - однородные определения.проснувшейся могучей реки - определения.

Comment: Спасибо. Не задумывалась, что это двойной союз.